# function to check variables in python

Tags: python, variables

```
b = 2
while True:
  if b == '2':
    print("2")
  if b == '3':
    print("3")
```

---

Hello, 
I was trying to make a simple game and was busy implementing a feature to toggle something on or off and it wasn't working and I am not sure why.
/:

Comment: You are comparing `int` with `str`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean. Thanks for answering

Comment: why not just `print b`?

Comment: b is an integer and '2' is character which are not equal , so you cant compare in them in python , But you can do this in languages like javascript . To do this in python convert it to string by typing `str(b)`

Comment: Even if this works, it is an endless loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

b is int not string. Your if checking that it equal to 2 string not int. Check b to string or if to int.

```
b = 2

while True:

  if b == 2:

    print("2")

  if b == 3:

    print("3")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. But the website won't let me make this the answer. But it is. Thanks (=

Comment: This answer is an endless loop since there is non-variable to turn True to false that is why the website doesn't let you put this answer because most probably it raises a RuntimeException error.

Answer (score 0):

This code is endless beside having issues with *int* and *str comparison* since **True** is always `True` and it will give a **Runtime exception**
if it is submitted as an answer.

```
b = 2
while True:
  if b == '2':
    print("2")
  if b == '3':
    print("3")
```

True one should be:

```
b = 2
not_equal = True

while not_equal:
  if b == 2:
    print("2")
    not_equal = False
  if b == 3:
    print("3")
    not_equal = False
```